# How to make a subscript of a subscript in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subscript

I know how to insert a subscript in a matplotlib plot using the following expression:

```
r'$P1_{ti-1}$'
```

However I would like to do a subscript of a subscript, something like:

`r'$P1_{t}_{i-1}$'`

where *t* is a subscript of *P1* and *i-1* is a subscript of *t* bt I cannot find any working example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible depending on how you nest your curly braces.

See the example below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.plot([1,2,3,],[1,2,3])
plt.text(s=r'$P1_{t_{i-1}}$',x=2, y=1.5, size=20)
plt.show()
```

[image: subscript on chart]

See [this overleaf doc page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Double_subscript) for more info.

Comment: No worries. Please consider accepting the answer if it was useful.